# awk NR==FNR for command syntax

Tags: bash, awk, fastq

I am having trouble using `awk` `NR==FNR` to return lines of interest from an input .fastq file.

I have the following example input file called `example.fastq`

```
@SRR1111111.1 1/1
CTGGANAAGTGAAATAATATAAATTTTTCCACTATTGAATAAAAGCAACTTAAATTTTCTAAGTCG
+
AAAAA#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEA<AAEEEEE<6
@SRR1111111.2 2/1
CTATANTATTCTATATTTATTCTAGATAAAAGCATTCTATATTTAGCATATGTCTAGCAAAAAAAA
+
AAAAA#EE6EEEEEEEEEEEEAAEEAEEEEEEEEEEEE/EAE/EAE/EA/EAEAAAE//EEAEAA6
@SRR1111111.3 3/1
CTATANTATTGAAATAATAATGTAGATAAAACTATTGAATAACAGCAACTTAAATTTTCAATAAGA
+
AAAAA#EE6EEEEEEEEEEEEAAEEAEEEEEEEEEEEE/EAE/EAE/EA/EAEAAAE//EEAEAA6
```

I am trying to extract groups of four lines that contain a string of interest, importantly approximate matches must be allowed hence the use of agrep instead of grep. The below example works.

```
agrep -1 -n "GAAATAATA" example.fastq | awk -F: 'NR==FNR{for(i=($1-1);i<=($1+2);i++)a[i];next}FNR in a' - example.fastq
```

The above command produces the following correct output.

```
@SRR1111111.1 1/1
CTGGANAAGTGAAATAATATAAATTTTTCCACTATTGAATAAAAGCAACTTAAATTTTCTAAGTCG
+
AAAAA#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEA<AAEEEEE<6
@SRR1111111.3 3/1
CTATANTATTGAAATAATAATGTAGATAAAACTATTGAATAACAGCAACTTAAATTTTCAATAAGA
+
AAAAA#EE6EEEEEEEEEEEEAAEEAEEEEEEEEEEEE/EAE/EAE/EA/EAEAAAE//EEAEAA6
```

However if I use a sequence not contained in the second line this command still prints the top two lines as in the following example.

```
agrep -1 -n "TAGATAAAACT" example.fastq | awk -F: 'NR==FNR{for(i=($1-1);i<=($1+2);i++)a[i];next}FNR in a' - example.fastq

@SRR1111111.1 1/1
CTGGANAAGTGAAATAATATAAATTTTTCCACTATTGAATAAAAGCAACTTAAATTTTCTAAGTCG
@SRR1111111.3 3/1
CTATANTATTGAAATAATAATGTAGATAAAACTATTGAATAACAGCAACTTAAATTTTCAATAAGA
+
AAAAA#EE6EEEEEEEEEEEEAAEEAEEEEEEEEEEEE/EAE/EAE/EA/EAEAAAE//EEAEAA6
```

Thanks for helping me understand the behavior of this awk command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `agrep + awk` solution:

```
srch() {
   awk -F ': ' 'NR==FNR {
      a[$1] = 1
      next
   }
   a[FNR] {
      print p
      print
      for (i=0; i<2 && getline > 0; i++)
         print
   }
   {
      p=$0
   }' <(agrep -1 -n "$2" "$1") "$1"
}
```

Then run it as:

```
srch file 'GAAATAATA'
```

```
@SRR1111111.1 1/1
CTGGANAAGTGAAATAATATAAATTTTTCCACTATTGAATAAAAGCAACTTAAATTTTCTAAGTCG
+
AAAAA#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEA<AAEEEEE<6
@SRR1111111.3 3/1
CTATANTATTGAAATAATAATGTAGATAAAACTATTGAATAACAGCAACTTAAATTTTCAATAAGA
+
AAAAA#EE6EEEEEEEEEEEEAAEEAEEEEEEEEEEEE/EAE/EAE/EA/EAEAAAE//EEAEAA6
```

and this:

```
srch file 'TAGATAAAACT
```

```
@SRR1111111.3 3/1
CTATANTATTGAAATAATAATGTAGATAAAACTATTGAATAACAGCAACTTAAATTTTCAATAAGA
+
AAAAA#EE6EEEEEEEEEEEEAAEEAEEEEEEEEEEEE/EAE/EAE/EA/EAEAAAE//EEAEAA6'
```

Comment: I think you have a stray `r=NR;` in there. You never read it.

Comment: Thanks but this solution doesn't facilitate approximate matches.  Is there a way to build in approximate match functionality so that a single mismatch will still return a result?

Comment: My bad i should have made it more clear.  I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

There are no colons (`:`) in your input, so `$1` refers to the whole line and `($1-1)` & `($2+2)` are going to be `-1` and `2` respectively, meaning your `for` loop will always run exactly four times (for values of `i` equal to `-1`, `0`, `1`, then `2`).

Inside the `for` loop, you're assuring that `a[i]` exists (that's `a[-1]`, `a[0]`, `a[1]`, and `a[2]`).

The final part of your code prints the line being examined at that time (but not from the first file thanks to the `next` in the prior stanza) whenever the array `a` contains an entry for that file's line number. Therefore, it prints lines 1 and 2 from each input (since `a[FNR]` exists for `FNR` equal to 1 or 2).

Since you need an approximate answer and therefore must use `agrep`, the idea proposed by [James Brown's answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53768989/519360) makes sense but its implementation (as dissected above) does not.

The following solution uses `agrep`'s hits as cues for surrounding lines to print alongside the hits (`agrep` does not support context lines like `grep`'s `-A NUM` and `-B num` or else we'd be able to do `agrep -A1 -B2 -1 -n PATTERN example.fastq` for a simpler answer).

```
agrep -1 "GAAATAATA" example.fastq | awk '
  NR == FNR { agrep_hit[$0] = 1; next }
  agrep_hit[$0] { print last_line; i = 1 }       
  0 < i && i < 4 { i++; print } 
  { last_line = $0 }
' - example.fastq
```

This examines the input file twice. The first time uses `agrep` to find the approximate pattern matches while the second uses `awk` to get the requested lines of context.

When the overall line number in `awk` (`NR`) equals the local file's line number (`FNR`), it means we're examining the first input (`-`, standard input, which is the output of `agrep`). We store the approximate pattern hits in an associative array for later and then move on to the next line with `next` (therefore the rest of the `awk` commands only operate on later inputs).

Since you need the previous line, we have to print it explicitly. The final stanza of `awk` code saves the current line as `last_line` so we can retrieve it later. Upon a line that was outputted by `agrep` (and thus stored in our array), we print that saved `last_line` and set an iterator `i` to `1`.

When `i` is `1`, `2`, or `3`, we increment it and print the current line. This prints the matching line and then two more for context.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful breakdown of the awk command syntax.  The use of agrep in the question is to allow mismatches that are not possible with grep.  Unfortunately agrep does not have the -B (before) and -A (after) arguments hence the use of awk as a workaround.  Please see this related post for more details on this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768447/grep-that-tolerates-mismatches-to-subset-fastq

Comment: I have revised my solution to reflect the need for `agrep`'s approximate pattern match and included your link to the source of that code in my answer. Please include such references in your future questions.

Comment: While I follow the logic and appreciate the explanation this solution is not generating any output for me.  Lines 1 and 2 work `./agrep/agrep -1 -n "GAAATAATA" example.fastq | awk 'NR==FNR { agrep_hit[$0] = 1; print }' - example.fastq` but I am unable to get any output by adding additional lines.

Comment: Sorry, I was assuming your `agrep` command was more sane; you forced me to `apt install agrep`. Just remove the `-n` and it will work (the prefixed line numbers prevented matching lines from the first read of the file to lines from the second read of the file). I've updated my answer to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

with record separator definition (GNU `awk`)

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)@' '/GAAATAATA/{printf "%s", rt $0} {rt=RT}' file

@SRR1111111.1 1/1
CTGGANAAGTGAAATAATATAAATTTTTCCACTATTGAATAAAAGCAACTTAAATTTTCTAAGTCG
+
AAAAA#EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEAEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEA<AAEEEEE<6
@SRR1111111.3 3/1
CTATANTATTGAAATAATAATGTAGATAAAACTATTGAATAACAGCAACTTAAATTTTCAATAAGA
+
AAAAA#EE6EEEEEEEEEEEEAAEEAEEEEEEEEEEEE/EAE/EAE/EA/EAEAAAE//EEAEAA6
```